Adding expect value to Playwright html report
I want to know how I can include the values I expect on in my Playwright html report.
It would be useful to see the URL and title I am expecting on to appear in the report.
expect.toHaveURL— ../src/objects/pages/pageObject.ts:18
expect.toHaveTitle— ../src/objects/pages/pageObject.ts:26
Snippet from report

You can add a custom expect message like this:
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";

test("Test", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");
  await page.getByRole("link", { name: "Get started" }).click();

  // As a second parameter in expect:
  await expect(page, "Expect url: https://playwright.dev/docs/intro").toHaveURL(
    "https://playwright.dev/docs/intro"
  );
});

Will show like this in the html report:

